# Will google assistant allow the same account in two different phones

Tags: applications, google-play-store, ios

I want to know will google assistant allow the same account in two different phones?

Will the messages or any other information will goes to secondary phone where the account is linked

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can use it on more smartphones at the same time. But you need to connect the other phone with your Google account. And then Google synchronizes everything. Your search history, contacts and more. Hope this helps you.

Sorry for my bad english.